# Why fopen fails in simple assembly call? [Warning: long assembly source]

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, fopen

Environment, Win 7. Using NASM, gcc (MINGW)

I have the following very simple assembly source:

```
SECTION .data       ; initialized data
    fname:      db  "c:\asmplus\tsources\s1.txt", 0
    fread:      db  "r", 0
    mopf:       db  "[FILE] open: %s", 10, 0

SECTION .text       ; code
    extern _fopen
    extern _printf  

    push        DWORD               fname
    push        DWORD               mopf
    call        _printf
    add         esp,    8           ; clean up stack use

    mov         DWORD [esp],        fname
    mov         DWORD [esp + 4],    fread
    call        _fopen
```

I get the following output:

> [FILE] open: c:\asmplus\tsources\s1.txt

... and then a Windows dialog saying the application has crashed. I don't have any sort of debugger available so I broke this down to the simplest source and tried it just like this. The file is available and not open. Is there anything specifically wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**
*full code added @Jester's request*

parse.asm

```
SECTION .data           ; initialized data
    mend:       db  10, "*** END ***", 10, 0

    mopf:       db  "open_file", 0

    mcll:       db  "[MAIN] call %s: %s", 10, 0
    mret:       db  "[MAIN] ret: %d", 10, 0


SECTION .text use32     ; code
    extern open_file
    extern _printf

    global _main

    _main:
        ;   stash base stack pointer
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,    esp

        mov     eax,    [ebp + 8]   ; num args
        mov     ebx,    [ebp + 12]  ; address of args (strings)
        mov     ecx,    0           ; init counter register to 0

        .do:
            push    ebp
            push    eax
            push    ecx

            mov     [c],    ecx

            ;   only expect args[1] to contain the file name
            mov     eax,    1
            cmp     eax,    [c]
            jne     .cont
            jmp     .openFile

            .cont:
                pop     ecx
                pop     eax
                pop     ebp

                add     ebx,    4       ; move to next arg
                inc     ecx             ; increment counter

                cmp     ecx,    eax
                jne     .do

        .openFile:
            push    DWORD   [ebx]
            push    DWORD   mopf
            push    DWORD   mcll
            call    _printf
            add     esp,    12

            push    DWORD   [ebx]
            call    open_file           ; should push result to eax

            mov     eax,    [ebp + 8]   ; stash file handle from stack
            mov     [fh],   eax         ; into fh variable

            add     esp,    4           ; clean up stack

            push    DWORD   [fh]
            push    DWORD   mret
            call    _printf
            add     esp,    8           ; clean up stack

        .end:
            push    DWORD   mend
            call    _printf
            ;   restore base stack pointer
            mov     esp,    ebp
            pop     ebp

SECTION .bss            ; uninitialized data
    c:      resd    1
    fh:     resd    1
```

fileops.asm

```
;   Contains file operations: 
;       open_file
;       ... TODO: read/write/close

SECTION .data       ; initialized data
    fread:      db  "r", 0

    merr:       db  "[FILE] error [%d:%d] %s", 10, 0
    mopf:       db  "[FILE] open: %s", 10, 0

SECTION .text       ; code
    extern _fopen
    extern _printf

    global open_file

    open_file:
        ;   stash base stack pointer
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,    esp

        mov     eax,        [ebp + 8]
        mov     [fnarg],    eax
        push    DWORD       [fnarg]
        push    DWORD       mopf
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    8

        ;   open file
        push    DWORD  fread
        push    DWORD  [fnarg]
        call    _fopen
        add     esp,    8

        push    DWORD   [eax]
        xor     eax,    eax

        .done:
        ;   restore base stack pointer
        mov     esp,    ebp
        pop     ebp

        ret

SECTION .bss        ; uninitialized data
    fnarg:      resb    128             ; reserve 128 bytes for file name
    fhndl:      resd    1
```

current output:

> D:\asmplus>.\exes\parse .\tsources\s1.txt
>   [MAIN] call open_file: .\tsources\s1.txt
>   [FILE] open: .\tsources\s1.txt
>   [MAIN] ret: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that all of your code? If you don't have anything after it, it will of course crash, since you don't terminate your program properly by doing `call _exit` or simply returning.

Also note you clean up the stack by the `add esp, 8` so you no longer have the space available that you are trying to move the arguments into. You are overwriting stuff on the stack, such as the return address, which will cause you problems if you ever try to return from your function for example. You can move that `add` down to after the `call _fopen` when you really don't need the slots any longer.

A corrected version could look something more like:

```
push        DWORD               fname
push        DWORD               mopf
call        _printf

mov         DWORD [esp],        fname
mov         DWORD [esp + 4],    fread
call        _fopen
add         esp,    8           ; clean up stack use
xor         eax, eax            ; 0 return value
ret
```

-or-

```
push        DWORD               fname
push        DWORD               mopf
call        _printf
add         esp,    8           ; clean up stack use

push        DWORD               fread
push        DWORD               fname
call        _fopen
add         esp,    8           ; clean up stack use
xor         eax, eax            ; 0 return value
ret
```

Comment: I am terminating properly. A basic test prior to implementing `call _fopen` printed the desired output and terminated properly. It is in this specific section that the application is crashing. :)

Comment: As I said, if by "terminating properly" you mean using a `ret` then that will fault because your code messed up the stack. Post complete code unless you know where the problem is in which case solve it yourself :P

Comment: You helped me figure out what was wrong. In my original app, I am passing a command argument file name to my open_file function. I believe I found where I was incorrectly moving the argument off the stack and into a variable. It appears to be working now. Thanks!